# Is stock trading based more on luck than poker playing?

Tags: trading, shares

Can it be calculated/measured?

My intuition says that stock trading is more about luck.

Comment: Will a confirmation of your intuition make you trade stocks more or play more poker? In short, "Do you feel lucky?" or are you justly proud of your poker skills?

Comment: I'm not proud of my poker skills, because I've lost everything I've played (40 euros). I don't trade stocks either.

Comment: Both are about luck if you don't have a plan. If you take the time and effort to develop a plan, both share trading and pocker can both be profitable businesses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say that it *cannot* be meaningfully calculated or measured because the two are just too different in every way.

**Poker**

1. is zero-sum
2. all individual games are fully independant of each other.
3. has a large random component, but the properties of this random influence are exactly statistically known.
4. players have incomplete knowledge due to said randomness, but all have the same amount of knowledge.
5. player skill consists of knowing said statistics and analyzing and influencing the behavior of individual other players.
6. can be played as a game of luck, but if you do so, skilled players will eat you alive.

**Stock trading**

1. is zero-sum in the short term, but not in the long term.
2. a large number of games is constantly running in parallel (and even overlapping), and they are all highly correlated (this may be the most fundamental difference).
3. has almost no truly random components, but an effectively infinite number of influencing factors, which can make it *appear* random.
4. players have incomplete knowledge because of that. But the amount of knowledge varies widely between players.
5. player skill consists of gaining more knowledge (research, fundamental analysis, insider trading), identifying which influence factors are most important (fundamental analysis), and finding and exploiting correlations (technical analysis).
6. can be played as a game of luck, but if you do so, you'll just lose money on trading fees.

I guess the last point (that someone relying on luck is exploitable in poker but not in stock trading) could be interpreted as stock trading being based more on luck, while the second and third points indicated that poker has more true randomness and is thus based more on luck.

Something both have in common is that people who have been losing money are often tempted to take stupid risks which lose them everything.

Answer (score 1):

This depends strongly on what you mean by "stock trading".  It isn't a single game, but a huge number of games grouped under a single name.

You can invest in individual stocks. If you're willing to make the (large) effort needed to research the companies and their current position and potentialities, this can yield large returns at high risk, or moderate returns at moderate risk. You need to diversify across multiple stocks, and multiple kinds of stocks (and probably bonds and other investment vehicles as well) to manage that risk.

Or you can invest in managed mutual funds, where someone picks and balances the stocks for you. They charge a fee for that service, which has to be subtracted from their stated returns. You need to decide how much you trust them. You will usually need to diversify across multiple funds to get the balance of risk you're looking for, with a few exceptions like Target Date funds.

Or you can invest in index funds, which automate the stock-picking process to take a wide view of the market and count on the fact that, over time, the market as a whole moves upward. These may not produce the same returns on paper, but their fees are MUCH lower -- enough so that the actual returns to the investor can be as good as, or better than, managed funds. The same point about diversification remains true, with the same exceptions.

Or you can invest in a mixture of these, plus bonds and other investment vehicles, to suit your own level of confidence in your abilities, confidence in the market as a whole, risk tolerance, and so on.

Having said all that, there's also a huge difference between "trading" and "investing", at least as I use the terms. Stock trading on a short-term basis is much closer to pure gambling -- unless you do the work to deeply research the stocks in question so you know their value better than other people do, and you're playing against pros. You know the rule about poker: If you look around the table and don't see the sucker, he's sitting in your seat... well, that's true to some degree in short-term trading too. This isn't quite a zero-sum game, but it takes more work to play well than I consider worth the effort.

Investing for the long term -- defining a balanced mixture of investments and maintaining that mixture for years, with purchases and sales chosen to keep things balanced -- is a positive sum game, since the market does drift upward over time at a long-term average of about 8%/year. If you're sufficiently diversified (which is one reason I like index funds), you're basically riding that rise. This puts you in the position of betting *with* the pros rather than against them, which is a lower-risk position. Of course the potential returns are reduced too, but I've found that "market rate of return" has been entirely adequate, though not exciting. Of course there's risk here too, if the market dips for some reason, such as the "great recession" we just went through -- but if you're planning for the long term you can usually ride out such dips, and perhaps even see them as opportunities to buy at a discount.

Others can tell you more about the details of each of these, and may disagree with my characterizations ... but that's the approach I've taken, based on advice I trust. I could probably increase my returns if I was willing to invest more time and effort in doing so, but I don't especially like playing games for money, and I'm getting quite enough for my purposes and spending near-zero effort on it, which is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I assert not so. Even if we assume a zero sum game (which is highly in doubt); the general stock market curves indicate the average player is so bad that you don't have to be very good to have better that 50/50 averages.

One example: UP stock nosedived right after some political mess in Russia two years ago. Buy! Profit: half my money in a month. I *knew* that nosedive was senseless as UP doesn't have to care much about what goes on in Russia. Rising oil price was a reasonable prediction; however this is good for railroads, and most short-term market trends behave as if it is bad.